# Selecting a vector from a matrix without using `sub2ind`

Tags: matlab

I have a 5 x 5 matrix M and two vectors

```
x=[1:5]
y=[1 4 3 5 2]
```

I would like to extract the elements of M with subscripts (x,y), i.e. (1,1),(2,4),(3,3),(4,5),(5,2). Of course, I could do something like

```
M(sub2ind([5,5],x,y))
```

But there is some overhead associated with the conversion to indices. Is there another way to do the same?

Comment: Does simply doing `M(x,y)` not work?

Comment: `diag(M(x,y))` should work, but I'm not sure how efficient it is

Answer (score 3):

MATLAB uses Column Major format, why not exploit that?
M is 5x5
So,
The first column is M(1), M(2), M(3), M(4), M(5).
So, Generalizing this:

> M(x,y) = M((x+(y-1)*5)

Comment: I think sub2ind might be a bit faster.

Comment: Nopes. I tested it repeatedly. `>> a = rand(5000,5000);
>> x = 1:5000;
>> y = randperm(5000);
>> tic;p2=a(x+(y-1)*5000);toc;           
Elapsed time is 0.000732 seconds.
>> tic;p=a(sub2ind([5000,5000],x,y));toc;
Elapsed time is 0.001371 seconds.
`

Comment: `sub2ind` does basically the same, the overhead just associated with error checking, generalization etc. Look at `sub2ind.m`.

Comment: I know but why use unnecessary overheads when you know what you are doing?

Answer (score 1):

You could do this using anonymous function handles in combination with the arrayfun method:

```
% declare an anonymous function which operates on M with args x and y
fun = @(x,y)(M(x,y)); 
% Ask arrayfun to execute "fun" for each pair of x and y.
arrayfun(fun, x, y);
```

Comment: +1 - Creative. But there should be some overhead like the initial approach, or even more.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer. But since I was interested I run tests of my own.

```
M = magic(5)
x=[1:5];
y=[1 4 3 5 2];

%%
tic
for i=1:10000
    out = M(sub2ind([5,5],x,y));
end
toc % Elapsed time is 0.413526 seconds.
out
%%
tic
for i=1:10000
    out = M(x+(y-1)*5);
end
toc % Elapsed time is 0.024004 seconds.
out
%%
fun = @(x,y)(M(x,y)); 
tic
for i=1:10000
    out = arrayfun(fun,x,y);
end
toc % Elapsed time is 0.449727 seconds.
out
%%
fun = @(x,y)(M(x,y)); 
tic
for i=1:10000
    out = nan(1,5);
    for j=1:5
        out(j) = M(x(j),y(j));
    end
end
toc % Elapsed time is  0.045242 seconds.
out
```

(sorry had a stupid copy-paste error in the first program)

I didn't expext the for loop to come out second.

I'm on 2011b - so seems it improved a lot.

Comment: on those times.. *BARF*

Answer (score 0):

I think your sub2ind approach is the fastest.

If you think about readability - maybe read in a for loop.

Comment: Do you mean code readability? I though for loops are a big no-no in matlab array operations since they have massive overhead?

Comment: They perform very poorly. But for debugging they are easier to read than most of these vectorized constructs.

Comment: Also for is a standard construct used in many languages. It's just a shame that they still haven't fixed this in matlab - but it gets better with every version.

Comment: It's a myth that for loops in MATLAB have "massive overhead", this used to be true at some point, like say, 8 years ago. With the introduction of JIT'd code and other optimizations, vectorization is no longer as important as it used to be, and can even be detrimental in some cases.